# Saving the number of clicks the user have done in a Button, Storing it in the LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, local-storage

I'm Making a Two Button in HTML,CSS and Javascript. The first button is called "Call Button" and second button is "Skip Button".

The process/scenario is :

1. The Skip Button is Disabled,
2. It will only be Enabled when 'Call Button' was Clicked 3 times.
3. If 'Call Button' was Clicked Three Times by the User, The Skip BUtton will be enable.

I have already made the function for the said process and scenario.

The problem is, Everytime I clicked the "Call Button" the Page refresh and the counter for the button is always refreshing turning it into zero(0) value every time I click "Call Button".

Now is it possible to store the 'Counter' in a LocalStorage?

How Can I implement it in my Code? Its my First time using this kind of function.

I highly appreciate it.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
    
        // Function for counting the number of times the user clicked the call button
        let counter = 0;

        function enableButton() {
       
            checker += 1;
            if(counter === 3){
                document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="enableButton()">Call Button</button>
    <button type="button" id="button2" disabled>Skip Button</button>
</body>
</html>`
```

The Above Code is a Example of my work. But on my original project, it has an refresh/reload function on button.

Comment: It definitely is possible. Have you taken a look a the [`localStorage documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: Thank you for checking my question Mr. @Geshode, Yes I already check the documentation, But I'm having quite a problem on implementing on it, I can't visualize the process on how can the Counter will be stored in the LocalStorage.

Comment: Why would you want to use localStorage? For a page refresh to keep up with the count? Otherwise it's not needed. Variables are there to be used for that scenario.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan As I understood it, the "call button" function reloads the page and thus resets the variable to 0. So, OP wants to use localStorage to have a way of knowing how many times the button has been clicked.

Comment: @Geshode nope. The page is **not** refreshed (you can see that the favicon does not spins when you hit that button). There's no reason to store anything in LS.

Comment: @Geshode Yes your correct on the idea of using the LocalStorage.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Why do you say, that it is not refreshed? The OP wrote in the question, that "The Above Code is a Example of my work. But on my original project, it has an refresh/reload function on button." So, the example doesn't have the refresh function shown, but it exists in the original project.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the code I pasted in here is just an example of my original code, in my original code it has a refresh function. I just can't post my original code for confidentiality. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Paquito may I just ask then (out of curiosity), why do you refresh the page? What's the purpose of refreshing that website? This reminds me of an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have some features on my project that works only when the page is refreshed.

Comment: @Mr.Paquito what features? Also, are you sure that your click handler will be quick enough to be registered before that other function click (that refreshes uselessly the app) kicks in?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It like a call features where when I clicked the "Call Button" There will be an announcement in a TV calling there names.

Comment: @Mr.Paquito hm, anyways... Another question, you need to loop forever 0-3, 0-3, ... or do it just once?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Need to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways of doing it, but this is an example of how to store the counter in localStorage:

```
let counter = localStorage.getItem("clickCounter");
if (counter === null) {
    counter = 0;
} else {
    counter = parseInt(counter)
}

function enableButton() {
    counter += 1;

    localStorage.setItem("clickCounter", counter.toString());      
    if(counter >= 3){
        document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

You have to parse the item from the localStorage, since you can only store strings.

Comment: What assures you that the page is not already reloading?

Comment: Nothing, since I don't know what the rest of OP's code looks like. I am just answering based on what OP has shown us.

Comment: PS: One line of code instead of 5: `let counter = Number(localStorage.clickCounter ?? 0)`

Comment: Also, there's no need to use `.toString()` since it *will* be converted to string automatically. Just use `localStorage.clickCounter = counter;`

Comment: I'll try this @Geshode Thanks, I'll update you if this works on my problem.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the tips. Didn't know about the nullish coalescing operator before. Learning something new every day.

Comment: @Mr.Paquito  This answer is correct . Incase you want to prevent the page from reloading use  "event.preventDefault()"